# How to open a file with it's own program with a linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, file-extension

I have developed a website using Asp.net. In a section of my program users need to download some variable files. (Jpeg,Pdf,doc,docx...) As they push the download button and hit "Open" button instead of "save" button, the file will open with Adobe Acrobat. The problem is that if it is a word file, again it will be open with Adobe Acrobat!
How can i avoid this and each file open with it's own program?
I used this cod in my behind cod:

```
   protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int idx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string Manuscript = GridView2.DataKeys[idx].Value.ToString();

        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Manuscript);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(Manuscript));
        Response.End(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.File1.PostedFile.FileName);
string contenttype = String.Empty;
```

OR

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

switch(ext)
{
    case ".doc":
        contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
        break;
    case ".docx":
        contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
        break;
    case ".xls":
        contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        break;
    case ".xlsx":
        contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        break;
    case ".jpg":
        contenttype = "image/jpg";
        break;
    case ".png":
        contenttype = "image/png";
        break;
    case ".gif":
        contenttype = "image/gif";
        break;
    case ".pdf":
        contenttype = "application/pdf";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, contenttype is not supported in the my cod! Does it need any name space?

Comment: @SaeedTalaee it is a string type which you have to decalre.

Comment: Check this link:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-save-insert-Image-in-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Ok i got it, File1 is the FileUpload control that you have to use from toolbox, if you have already FileUpload control on you ASP.NET for replace File1 with your FileUpload name

Comment: Well, I have already uploaded my file! and i am working with it's saved address, so i think i have to replace it with an address file  which is a string. Isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately the download action is not occur! I have trace the cod and every thing works fine, but the download action wont happen!!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
string fileExtn = fInfo.Extension;
```

Comment: Thanks, What is the name space for FileInfo ?

Comment: You're welcome. Its `System.IO`. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx. Please upvote and accept if my answer helps you.

Comment: You dont have to worry about namespaces, if you dont know the namespace paste the code and click of FileInfo and Visual Studio will suggest the appropraite namespace to you, click on that and it will be added automatically